# Related object across many table

Tags: database-design

## The problem

I'm building a database about book that currently as the following tables

- book
- part
- chapter
- paragraph

with the expected one-to-many relation ship (ie book has many part, with many chapter,...).

I want to be able to mark any pair of row across those table as related. For example, this book is related to this chapter or this chapter is related to this other chapter. This relation is reflective. I'm wondering about what's the best way to store this information.

The usage would the mostly be to retrieve all item related to an item.

I've so far considered two ideas.

## Idea 1

Use many table of the form `book_chapter_related_map` with to foreign key making the connection between a book and a chapter. I would have one such table of each pair, ie 10 tables.

## Idea 2

One single table with four columns, `fk1`, `table1`, `fk2`, table2`.

## Comparison

The first idea allow the database to enforce the foreign key constraint and have join operation but create many tables. While the other one is only one table but retrieving information is a bit ad hoc

I've google a bit around but did not found any similar design. Surely I'm not the first one thinking about that. Any take on how to design this or ressources?

p.s On a similar theme I'm also considering having a tag table that I would need to be able connect to book, part, chapter and paragraph.